# Java ArrayList OutofBounds when adding an item

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this array:

```
ArrayList<Problem> problems = new ArrayList <Problem>( 100 );
```

then I try to make an object to put in it:

```
Problem p = new Problem ();
p.setProblemName( "Some text" );
```

Then I try to add the object to the array:

```
problems.set(1, p);
```

But at this point the system throws a runtime exception:

```
03-12 18:58:04.573: E/AndroidRuntime(813): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
```

But if I increase the initial size of the array to 100. Why does this error happen? It seems this is super straight forward.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `set` to add to an `ArrayList` you use it to overwrite an existing element.

```
problems.set(1, p); //Overwrite the element at position 1
```

You use `add`

```
problems.add(p);
```

will add it at the end

```
problems.add(1, p);
```

will add it at index 1, this will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException for 
 index < 0 or  index > `ArrayList.size()`. Which will be the case on the first attempt for an add.

Also just for your knowledge

```
problems.add(ArrayList.size(), p); //Works the same as problems.add(p);
```

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList#set()`

Throws:
`IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the index is out of range `(index < 0 || index >= size())`

`size()` returns number of elements in the array list, not the capacity.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `ArrayList<Problem> problems = new ArrayList <Problem>( 100 );`, you only tell Java that you think you are going to use that kind of capacity (which optimises the size of the underlying array) but the list still has a size of 0.

You need to use `add()`:

```
problems.add(p);
```

will add p in the first position.

```
List<Problem> problems = new ArrayList <Problem>();
Problem p = new Problem ();
p.setProblemName( "Some text" );

problems.add(p);

Problem p2 = problems.get(0); //p2 == p
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write this instead:

```
problems.add(0, p);
```

You haven't any 0th member that you want to insert p into 1st place!

Comment: Set won't work. The `ArrayList` has no elements yet so Size = 0. Set throws and IndexOfOutBoundsException if the index is >= size.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
problems.set(0, p);
```

the first position in an array is always 0.

*edit* you should be using the .add() method to add an object to the array though

Comment: when I set it to 0, I get this error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: Set will not work if there isn't an element in the list already. He has to use add. Set fails in `index < 0 || index >= size`. With a size=0 set always fails.